# Div's width set in vw, but doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, width, viewport-units

I have a problem with CSS (or at least I think that the problem is in CSS). I set everything in vw, but it acts weirdly. In big resolution it looks normaly, but in small resolution it doesn't.

You can see it on [this](http://mc2.devicarus.eu/test.gif) GIF (it was too large to upload here). As you can see, when the screen is smaller, the last div moves down under the first one.

Here is live demo: http://mc2.devicarus.eu/

```js
var width = document.getElementById("box1").offsetWidth;
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
box1.style.height = width + "px";
var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
box2.style.height = width + "px";
var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
box3.style.height = width + "px";
```

```css
div.boxes {
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

div.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0.15vw;
  width: 24.7667vw;
  background: url('http://mc2.devicarus.eu/img/wood.png');
  background-size: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.8vw;
  margin-right: 0.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" id="box1">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: use `display:table` or `flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:table` like following...

```css
div.boxes {
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  margin-top: 3%;
  display:table;    /* Added */
}

div.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0.15vw;
  width: 24.7667vw;
  background: url('http://mc2.devicarus.eu/img/wood.png');
  background-size: 150px;
  display: table-cell;  /* Added */
  margin-left: 0.8vw;
  margin-right: 0.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" id="box1">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Use `display:flex` like following...

```css
div.boxes {
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  margin-top: 3%;
  display: inline-flex;  /* Added */
}

div.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0.15vw;
  width: 24.7667vw;
  background: url('http://mc2.devicarus.eu/img/wood.png');
  background-size: 150px;
  /* display: table-cell; */
  margin-left: 0.8vw;
  margin-right: 0.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" id="box1">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">

  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">

  </div>
</div>
```